# Can consistent reads cause a Lock Timeout Excedeed error?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

I have a PHP function which executes a few SQL queries, a series of SELECTs/INSERTs.

SELECTs read from standard tables (InnoDB) and INSERTs are done in temporary tables (Memory). None of them are executed inside a transaction (I couldn't do that even if I wanted to cause MySQL 5.7 does not support the use of temporary tables within transactions when GTIDs are enabled).

For a while, these queries returned a "Lock timeout exceeded" error which I can't make sense of since there is no transactions and all SELECTs are consistent reads? I can't imagine INSERTs being a problem either since all temporary tables are scoped to this thread/connection and are only used once.

Clearly I must be missing something obvious?

Comment: You will get more traction on SO if you add the relevant code so we can see whats really going on

Comment: Are you using `INSERT INTO my_temp_table SELECT ... FROM my_real_table`? That causes an implicit shared lock on the real table. Anytime you do a read in the same SQL statement with a write, it acts as if you had used `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE`.

Comment: I'm aware of that, RiggsFolly, though I am not allowed to post this code. Anyhows, it's simply a series of CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE <random name>; INSERT INTO <random name> SELECT ... Curiously, this lock timeout exceeded error has never happened prior to today and it's not happening right now so I can't easily reproduce it. But I would still like to make some sense of how it could've happened. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Bill, it's an honour talking to you! Yes, that's exactly the case. It sounds totally new to me that an INSERT INTO temp_table SELECT ... FROM real_table would place a shared lock on rows it reads (I suppose).

Comment: Thanks a lot, then. That explains it. Though I suppose there is no way around this?

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html on the section starting with **INSERT INTO T SELECT ... FROM S WHERE ...** It also applies to `REPLACE ... SELECT` or `UPDATE ... WHERE ... (SELECT...)` or `SELECT INTO @var ...` or `SELECT` run inside a trigger. Anytime you do a read as part of a write operation.

Comment: The shared locks won't conflict with each other, but if any other session tries to INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE on your original table, those require exclusive locks, which are blocked by shared locks. This might explain why you haven't seen this happen all the time.

Comment: Thanks! It all makes sense now.

Comment: The only way I know to work around it is to do the `SELECT` as a pure read, and fetch the result back to a client app. Then use the rows fetched to `INSERT` into the temp table as a separate statement.

Comment: Which isn't viable in my case due to the number of rows. Now that I know, I will plan accordingly. Thanks again.